# SwiftUI: Update UI after background thread has finished

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, swiftui

In my app I import a JSON file and display its content in the app. In order to avoid freezing of the UI, because the file can be bigger sometimes, I parse the file in a background thread and convert it into my internal swift structure. When the parsing is done, the view should be redrawn, as the content of the structure has changed. Because I mustn't change the view from a background thread I have some kind of workaround at the moment.
I start the parsing in the action of the `.fileImporter` modifier of a button like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    documentManager.parseInput()
}
```

And in the `parseInput` method in the `documentManager` I do something like this

```
func parseInput() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        inputIsParsed = false
    }
    
    // parse ...
            
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
        inputIsParsed = true
    }
}
```

`inputIsParsed` is a `@Published` variable in the `documentManager`, which is my ViewModel

```
 @Published var inputIsParsed = false
```

My question now is:
Is this as bad as I think it is or is there no better way that probably also involves a completely different concept of putting work into the background and redrawing the view when the calculation has finished?

Comment: you could try the new "task" modifier in ios 15, seems to be designed for this.

Comment: Thank you. It works great. This is a neat new feature.

Answer (score 1):

I think better method is to use `PassThroughSubject` that doesn't store it anywhere just publishes the change.

in your ViewModel you define:

```
var currentAction = PassthroughSubject<Action, Never>()
```

you also define `enum Action`:

```
enum Action {
    case inputParsed
    case anythingElseToReport
}
```

the advantage is you get to have greater flexibility. And you can observe it anywhere via:

```
var anyCancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

ViewModel.currentAction
        .sink { value in                
            switch value { //You can also use if value == Action.inputParsed
            case .inputParsed: return //Your action
            default: return
            }
        }
        .store(in: &anyCancellables)
```

PS: In SwiftUI views you use `.onReceive()` on the view to get the action instead of .sink.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a completion block closure or delegate to know when data is loaded and then return to main thread to update UI.

```
func loadData(completion: @escaping(Data?) -> Void) {
    // Parse your data here instead
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        completion(Data())
    }
}
    
func loadDataAndUpdateUI() {
    loadData { data in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // update ui
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same thing, running some stuff on background threads and then updating the UI via async operation on the main thread I could not find any other way.
To make this process easier, I am using a function that makes sure the operation is running on the main thread. I find it as something that makes my code simpler since many times we are running inside async functions that we are not sure whether they are in the main thread or another background thread (suppose you use some 3rd party API and it invokes an async callback - you cannot be sure where your code is running now)

So I am using this global function:

```
func RunInMainThread(execute: @escaping ()->Void) {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
         execute()
    }
    else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            execute()
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, just do something like:

```
RunInMainThread {
    inputIsParsed = true
}
```

Comment: As @workingdog pointed out on my post, there is the new .task() modifier in iOS 15. I found that pretty useful. It helps you too probably